# How to display Audio Player in Post Excerpt?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Wordpress plugin, [Audio Player](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/audio-player/).

While it displays perfectly in a Full Post after clicking on "Read More...", it displays 
`[Audio clip: view full post to listen]` in the Excerpt Preview.

I imagine it is because of Wordpress stripping Shortcodes, but I'm not entirely sure.

For the website I am creating, I **need** the Audio Player to show up on the Category & Home Page.

**Any** Feedback is **GREATLY** appreciated.

---

**Excerpt Picture**

[image: Excerpt]

---

**Full Post Picture**

[image: Full Post]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

Comment: Where would I add that line to?

Comment: In your theme directory, there is a file called functions.php - this needs to go in there, anywhere in the file (to be safe, right after the opening `<?php`)